# Exception in popular nouns

Tags: grammar, singular

I have no idea if it's because of whether informal English or not, but I found this reporter talking about a boat passing by an iceberg and he was like:

> This iceberg here, there's outcroppings under the water. And uh, see ice, iceberg is so very hard, so it's like a can opener.

I was wondering when to use singulars with plurals like what was in the quote as you see, outcroppings is used with a singular to-be verb.

**Is there any special grammar behind this or just causal talks because I've heard in movies the same too?!**

Answer (score 0):

I think you're correct that this is just incorrect casual usage of "there's" which is pretty common. Incorrect use of contractions is pretty rampant even among many native speakers! Technically I don't think it's correct but people do not always speak with the best grammar.

Comment: If people are using it commonly, then by definition it is grammatical in their dialect. I don't feel it's grammatical in the more formal register of standard American/British/etc. English, however. That doesn't make it bad, it just means informal and more formal speech have different rules.